# I can't use my django model values in forms.py. I get : name 'user' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a value from a django model, but I'm missing something in my code and I can't figure out what it is.

I'm using django 1.11

Do I need the form class to inherit request? In case,how do I do that?

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

class form(forms.Form):
  department_string = ((user.profile.departnemt_1_number, 'Afd A',), ('2', 'Afd B',),)
  afdeling = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=department_string, initial='1')
```

I get: Exception Value: name 'user' is not defined

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define this at that point; there's no `user` in scope at the point where the form is defined.

You need to override the `__init__` method of your form to accept an extra keyword argument from the user and modify the choices appropriately.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  afdeling = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, initial='1')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     user = kwargs.pop('user')
     super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['afdeling'].choices = ((user.profile.departnemt_1_number, 'Afd A',), ('2', 'Afd B',),)
```

Don't forget to pass the user from the view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
       form = MyForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
       ...
    else:
       form = MyForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Why do I call the super method? Isn't it used to call a __init__ method from an inherited class? And what do you mean by overriding the __init__ method? Was there one before?

Comment: Yes, it is used to call a method from an inherited class, which is exactly what you are doing here.